# How to use different engine parameters for each fold with tidymodels during crossvalidation?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I would like to use tidymodels to tune a ranger random forest in a crossvalidated setup.
My dataset is unbalanced. Because of that I would like to use the ranger parameter **class.weights**.

However, each fold can have different weights.
How can I pass the fold specific weights to the engine?

MWE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(111)

iris_cut <- iris[30:110,] # Dummy unbalanced dataset

# Create folds  
folds <- vfold_cv(iris_cut, v = 3)

# Calculate class weights: 
calc_weights <- function(df) {
  weights <- df %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(n_total = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(weight = max(n_total)/n_total) %>% 
    distinct(n_total, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    .$weight 
  return(weights)
}

# Use during training of fold 1:
weights_fold1 <- folds$splits[[1]]$data[folds$splits[[1]]$in_id,] %>% calc_weights() 
# Use during training of fold 2:
weights_fold2 <- folds$splits[[2]]$data[folds$splits[[2]]$in_id,] %>% calc_weights()
# Use during training of fold 3:
weights_fold3 <- folds$splits[[3]]$data[folds$splits[[3]]$in_id,] %>% calc_weights()


# Defining a recipe
rec <- recipe(Species~ ., data = iris_cut) 
  
# Create Model Specification
rf_mod <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(), 
  trees = 1000, 
  min_n = 1
) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger",
             class.weights=!!weights_fold1 # Wrong! Here for each fold another weight vector should be passed
             )  

rf_grid <- crossing(
  mtry = c(1,2,3)
)
  
# Setup workflow 
tune_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>% 
  add_model(rf_mod)

# Start rf tuning
tune_res <- tune_grid( 
  tune_wf,
  resamples = folds,
  grid = rf_grid
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tidymodels ecosystem doesn't have support for passing those kinds of weights to folds. Instead, we encourage folks to use the [themis](https://themis.tidymodels.org/) package to handle class imbalance during feature engineering. There are multiple options for upsampling and downsampling.

For example, the SMOTE algorithm:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(themis)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'themis':
#>   method                  from   
#>   bake.step_downsample    recipes
#>   bake.step_upsample      recipes
#>   prep.step_downsample    recipes
#>   prep.step_upsample      recipes
#>   tidy.step_downsample    recipes
#>   tidy.step_upsample      recipes
#>   tunable.step_downsample recipes
#>   tunable.step_upsample   recipes
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'themis'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:recipes':
#> 
#>     step_downsample, step_upsample
set.seed(111)

iris_cut <- iris[30:110,] # Dummy unbalanced dataset

iris_rec <- recipe(Species ~ ., data = iris_cut) %>%
  step_smote(Species)
  
iris_rec %>% prep() %>% bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4 setosa 
#>  4          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#>  5          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  7          5           3.2          1.2         0.2 setosa 
#>  8          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1 setosa 
#> 10          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa 
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You can read more about subsampling during modeling [here](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/sub-sampling/) and [here](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#skip-equals-true).